# colliding 2 moving and rotating sprites in xna 2d

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I recently started making a game in windows phone XNA, I have a rocket in the middle that I can rotate and has a thrust to speed up in the direction it is facing and meteors coming out. The point is to survive as long as you can and avoid collision with the meteors. I can't manage to implement the collision between two moving and rotating sprites which are the rocket and a random meteor. I've seen rectangular collision which to me appears bad but maybe I am coding it a bit wrong and the pixel collision is way complicated :/ any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: use rectangle or/and circle collision. pixel collision will lag if you have a lot of objects.

Comment: You're using a big texture with many positions of an object or 1 texture for each position? I'll try to explain the pixel collision to you in an easy way.

Comment: I just added rotation to the sprite's Draw Method and set the Origiin to be Width/2 and Height/2 so it rotates around the center. I don't know if it's 1 texture for each position. I tried using rectangular collision detection by adding a method that calculates the vertices of each sprite's bounding rectangle with this formula http://prntscr.com/16ft4q  and then check for intersection with each side of the rectangle with each side of the other rectangle but it doesn't seem to work good. in fact it works pretty bad in some cases.

Comment: I don't know if it's calculating good because the sprites are rotating but I added that in my Update() method which should mean it calculates the vertices of each side of the bounding rectangle all the time something happens right ?

Comment: I think it should be 1 texture for each position 1 sprite 1 Texture2D

Comment: can you give me an example of rectangular collision of moving and/or rotating sprites?